# How can I sign an egg?

Tags: python, code-signing, egg

In java it is possible to sign a JAR file using `jarsigner` tool.

Is it possible to attach a SSL certificate to a python egg?

I searched for this but surprisingly little documentation turned up.

What support is there in python for distributing signed python applications?

Comment: [Wheel](http://wheel.readthedocs.org) may be useful to you.

Comment: @delnan I agree that should be an answer!

Comment: +1 for the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the egg format does not have any provisions for code signing. PyPI does provide you with an MD5 signature (as part of the download URL), but current tools do not verify this at the moment.

The newer [Wheel binary package format](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#signed-wheel-files) supports both cryptographic hashes and digital (S/MIME ) signatures; an installer is required to verify the hashes upon installation, digital signature verification is optional.

Note that due to Python's dynamic and flexible nature, there is little point in relying on signed code after installation, as another python module can completely change the code structures in any other Python module.

Comment: I don't agree, signed package cannot be easily substitutes and if someone will rely only on signed packages, its installation is less vulnerable to Trojan attempts.

Comment: @MichałF: PyPI provides MD5 signatures for that purpose. SSL certificates are about tampering with the installed code after installation too.